# Obtain a repeated data and send SQL mail

Tags: sql, sql-server

Good day I have a table called Ticket which has several tickets registered, each one has a status:

1 = Accepted,2 = Assigned,3 = At ​​attention,4 = Attended,5 = Agree.

I want to perform a stored procedure in which I only send mail to the tickets that are in state 4, that is, my ticket has status 4, it is activated `exec sp_sendmail .`

Then I will use it as a Job every 30 minutes, check to see if it is still in that state and if it is in state 4 it sends again mail, once it changes state 4 to 5 it will not send anything and it will be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, that loops through the list of tickets and sends an email. Couple notes, though: first, if you try to send too many at once, your email provider may start dropping them, so maybe put in a {pre}WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:02'{pre} delay between messages. Also, instead of sending one email per ticket, you can look into the query options in sp_send_dbmail: you can email a single list of all currently-4 tickets. It just depends on your needs.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SendTicketAttendedEmails 
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @MailList TABLE(TicketID INT, SendTo VARCHAR(255))
    DECLARE @ThisTicketID INT
        , @MailMessage NVARCHAR(2000)
        , @MailSubject NVARCHAR(255)
        , @SendTo VARCHAR(255)

    INSERT INTO @MailList
        ([TicketID], [SendTo])
    SELECT t.[ID], u.[UserEmail]
    FROM dbo.YourTicketTable t
        JOIN dbo.YourUserTable u
            ON t.UserCreated = u.ID
    WHERE [StatusID] = 4

    WHILE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @MailList)
    BEGIN

        SELECT TOP(1) @ThisTicketID = [TicketID]
            , @MailSubject = 'Ticket ' + CAST([TicketID] AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' is in status 4.'
            , @MailMessage = 'Please review, or whatever, ticket ' + CAST([TicketID] AS VARCHAR(10)) + '.'
            , @SendTo =  COALESCE([SendTo], 'yourEmailAddress@InCase.Missing')
        FROM @MailList
        ORDER BY [TicketID];

        DECLARE @mailitem_id INT ;
        EXEC [msdb].dbo.[sp_send_dbmail] 
            @profile_name = 'SomeDBMailProfileName'     -- sysname
            , @recipients = @SendTo                     -- varchar(max)
            , @subject = @MailSubject                   -- nvarchar(255)
            , @body = @MailMessage                      -- nvarchar(max)
            , @mailitem_id = @mailitem_id OUTPUT        -- int
            , @from_address = 'you@you.com'             -- varchar(max)
            , @reply_to = 'you@you.com'                 -- varchar(max)

        DELETE @MailList
        WHERE [TicketID] = @ThisTicketID

    END
END
```

Comment: if it served me, just that I need to send to several different emails how could I do it? 
State 4 of the ticket there are several users and you need to send those users.

Comment: Hi Gusttavo, I edited the code to show how you'd specify a different user. I had to assume that there was a user table with that information, tied to the ticket table. HTH!

Answer (score 0):

Basically you will use something like this for your job.

```
exec sp_send_dbmail 
   @profile_name = 'your_mail_profile'
  ,@recipients = 'you@email.com'
  ,@subject = 'Attended'
  ,@query = 'select * from yourTable where [status] = 4'
  --,@attach_query_result_as_file = 1
  --,@query_attachment_filename = 'somefile.csv'
```

See other options [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)... and adjust accordingly.